# How to copy a string into the X Window clipboard with the command line on Red Hat without using xsel nor any third-party tool?

Tags: scripting, x11, clipboard

On a restricted system where installing new tools is not possible, how could one copy a string into the X Window clipboard (the clipboard that works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) with the command line or at least in an automated way, without using xsel nor any other such third-party tool?

I am using Red Hat.

I would find it hard to believe that achieving such a basic task could not be done using native Linux only.

Comment: What does "native Linux only" mean? `xsel` _is_ a native Linux program, why don't you want to use that? And what Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Red Hat.
On some restricted systems you cannot install packages using a package manager such as apt, and also it is fairly complicated to install from sources. That is why I would need a solution that only uses Linux features that are "natively" present on the system. Something like "echo my_string > /dev/clipboard" would be perfect.

Comment: OK. But just so you know, none of that is a "Linux" feature which is why the question is confusing. Remember that Linux is just a kernel, nothing more, so _everything_ is done using "3rd party tools". Are you aware of middle click paste? You can select anything with your mouse, and that automatically copies it to a (different, not the X Window, clipboard), and you can then paste it by middle clicking. Perhaps that is an acceptable workaround for you? I don't think what you are asking for is possible without using something like `xsel`. That's why `xsel` exists, after all.

Comment: @terdon xsel and xclip are third-party in the sense that they aren't part of the basic X.org tool set.

Comment: @terdon Middle click paste is not an acceptable workaround because it is not really automated given that it requires a user input action (the press of a mouse button.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python standard library includes the [`tkinter` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) ([Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) in Python 2), and you can access the X clipboard through that.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, tkinter; sys.stdout.write(tkinter.Tk().clipboard_get())'
python2 -c 'import sys, Tkinter; sys.stdout.write(Tkinter.Tk().clipboard_get())'
```

You can also set the clipboard content, but that's a bit more invasive, because the clipboard content is owned by a running application. Programs like `xsel` leave a background process running while they own the clipboard. Here's a simple code fragment that you need to keep running until you're no longer interested in the content; close the window when you're done.

```
echo -n 'new clipboard content' | python3 -c 'import tkinter; w = tkinter.Tk(); w.clipboard_clear(); w.clipboard_append(input()); w.mainloop()'
echo -n 'new clipboard content' | python2 -c 'import Tkinter, sys; w = Tkinter.Tk(); w.clipboard_clear(); w.clipboard_append(sys.stdin.read()); w.mainloop()'
```

(There are better ways to access the clipboard in Python, such as [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) which is cross-platform and doesn't require displaying a window, but they aren't part of the standard library.)